# install DoctrineFixturesBundle and doctrine-fixtures in Symfony 2.1.4

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I want to install and configure **DoctrineFixturesBundle** and **doctrine-fixtures** in Symfony 2.1.4. Can anyone give me a guide.

Comment: in your composer.json ... "require": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master" }

Answer (score 8):

Your question may be already in answered in [DoctrineFixturesBundle issues](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues) section, anyway I will summarize the steps to install and configure DoctrineFixturesBundle in symfony 2.1.4 version.

Step 1 :

Open the *composer.json* and append below code in require section. This file is located in root folder of the project

```
{
    "require": {  
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Step 2:

Run below command in your terminal

```
php composer.phar update
```

Final Step:

append the below in your app/AppKernel.php

```
// ...
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
        // ...
    );
    // ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this helps me too. one thing you may update .. the use of "composer update" command direct and the installation of composer before and log out and log in